# DIY Antenna with minimum components for proof of concept

Tags: antenna, wireless

I am going to try a simple transmitter-receiver(assuming receiver circuit is same) circuit using the following circuit:
[image: Transmitter circuit]

Now, I have got the BJT part and the LC oscillator part figured out. What I need is now the design of antenna. Note that my constraints are: **I only need proof of concept**, that is I only need to see if wireless transmission is happening or not-for example in receiver circuit I will have an LED which will turn on/off on basis of source voltage at transmitter side.**There is no requirement for long range or ultra high frequency(I will set LC accordingly)**. I will place both circuits side by side(meaning not too far to raise concerns).

So, my question is **can I make a simple monopole or dipole antenna(or any antenna) with a jumper wire(or just a wire) or any other simple conductor without any coaxial cable, mounts, brackets, soldering equipment**. I just want a quick plug-in of a simple antenna to both circuits and check transmission(do consider the case if circuits are built on a breadboard). Whatever resources I have referred to now, they suggest antennas with complex components(with respect to my constraints above):
[image: DIY Monopole Antenna]

[image: Commercial Monopole Antenna]

Comment: Your receiver will be a far harder problem than you realize, at the level of current improbability you might just as well grab a length of wire.  If you had a known frequency you could apply dipole or monopole formula, but you do not...

Comment: Even if I had a known frequency, I am not sure if I could just make a dipole antenna out of a wire, plug it into the breadboard and make it work out, hence my question.

Comment: @PrasanjitRath:  Given the values in the circuit, I doubt that it will work on a solderless breadboard.  The capacitances are at approximately the same value as the capacitances between breadboard rows.  If you are soldering the co,ponents on a pieces of perf board, then you may get it to work.  Your circuit is a common "FM transmitter" circuit that can be found all over the internet.  You can test it with an FM radio receiver.  If it works, you should be able to hear it with any standard FM broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the circuit is for an FM wireless microphone, tunable on the 88 - 108 MHz FM broadcast band.

It's easier to build a simple transmitter than a simple receiver. So just go ahead and wire up the transmitter, but not on a breadboard. Point-to-point wiring with short leads would be better.

Check for oscillation and try to receive the signal on a nearby FM receiver. A 1m length of wire would do for an antenna.

Tuning would be touchy due to hand effects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.An antenna is just a piece of wire and an open circuit.

The length of the antenna for perfect transmission and reception should be 1/2 the wavelength of the transmitted / received wave